# How can I output 2 winning numbers in a 6 random lotto in JAVA?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and Stack Overflow. How can I output
just 2
matched numbers in the 6 random lotto?
Lotto is a lottery program made of 6 random numbers (Lotto 6/42).

Design a program that:

- Generates the 6 random numbers for the winning combination.
- Display the winning numbers to make it easier to check.

Display the prize of the lotto buyer based on the following:

- Winning Numbers (in any order)    Prize
- 6 winning numbers Minimum Jackpot prize of P9 Million
- 5 winning numbers P25,000.00
- 4 winning numbers P1,000.00
- 3 winning numbers P20.00

Code:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> winningNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        while (true) {
            int winningNumber = random.nextInt(49) + 1;
            if (!winningNumbers.contains(winningNumber)) {
                winningNumbers.add(winningNumber);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter 6 digit number: ");

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Integer> guess = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {

        while (true) {
            String numberString = key.nextLine();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
            if (number >= 1 && number<= 42) {
                guess.add(number);
                break;

            } else {
                System.out.println("INVALID, PLEASE TRY AGAIN");
                System.out.println("==========================");
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Your numbers are: " + guess);
    System.out.println("The winning numbers are: " + winningNumbers);

    guess.retainAll(winningNumbers);
    System.out.println("Your matched numbers are: " + guess);

    if (guess.containsAll(winningNumbers)) {
        System.out.println("YOU JUST WON 27 MILLION!");
    } else if (guess.contains(winningNumbers)) { // THIS LINE
        System.out.println("You have correct 3 numbers! Congratulations you won 20.00!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sad");
    }

}
```

and this is the output:

```
        Please enter 6 digit number: 
        24
        42
        3
        21
        17
        39
        Your numbers are: [24, 42, 3, 21, 17, 39]
        The winning numbers are: [32, 5, 24, 14, 22, 3]
        Your matched numbers are: [24, 3]
        Sad
    
        Process completed.
```

How could I make it like "You have 2 winning numbers and you won!"

Comment: `guess.size()` after `guess.retainAll` will give you the number of correct guesses

Answer (score 0):

`guess.contains(winningNumbers))` doesn't work because you are searching a List inside a List. You have to check single values.
I suggest something like:

```
int n=0; //number of occurrencies
for(int i=0;i<guess.size();i++)
{
    if(winningNumbers.contains(guess.get(i)))
         n++;
}
```

By doing this, in `n` you have the number of occurrencies, then you can use it in a switch:

```
switch(n)
{
    case(1): //one number correct
    break;
    case(2): //2 numbers correct
    break;
    case(3): //3 numbers correct
    break;
    case(4): //4 numbers correct
    break;
    case(5): //5 numbers correct
    break;
    case(6): //6 numbers correct
    break;
    default: //error
    break;
}
```